# Spring MVC cache control headers on JSON content

Tags: http, spring-mvc

I've got an application where I'm using a text editor to insert images and banners etc. It gets the banner by calling an AJAX request to get the banner, then it compiles the JS.

I want a quick/easy way to cache the request. So I was hoping to just cache the response in the browser cache for 30 seconds.

So I'm trying to get it working in Chrome, but it keeps sending the request and the server keeps responding 200 Ok.

Here's the relevant part of my web config:

```
WebContentInterceptor webContentInterceptor = new WebContentInterceptor();
webContentInterceptor.setUseCacheControlHeader(true);
webContentInterceptor.setUseExpiresHeader(true);
webContentInterceptor.setUseCacheControlNoStore(true);
webContentInterceptor.setCacheSeconds(30);

registry.addInterceptor(webContentInterceptor);
```

And the cache control headers as per chrome:

```
Request URL:https://localhost:8443/admin/banners/json/by_shortcode/banner_test
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:sidebar_closed=1; SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE=UmljaGFyZC5HaWxsaW5nQGdtYWlsLmNvbToxNDIzODgzOTI1MTY4OmU1OGM2YzVjNjIwMWIyNWM3OTZlMWM5MThjMDc0MDg4; JSESSIONID=70842F221D3172686E406242AD3F5E02
Host:localhost:8443
Referer:https://localhost:8443/admin/pages/new
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.94 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Response Headers

Cache-Control:max-age=30
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 02 Feb 2015 14:03:13 GMT
Expires:Mon, 02 Feb 2015 14:03:43 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

What I'm wondering is:

a) Why is the browser re-requesting the same request within the 30 second window? I am hoping to cache it for 30seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you tell the browser not to cache anything: `Pragma:no-cache`.

Comment: I think that might be because of Spring Security - I found a couple of related questions that talk about Security injecting it's own headers to stop caching....